# Azure V2 - calling a custom web api from .net web app

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying below mentioned sample to call a web api protected by Azure V2 endpoint:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-webapp-webapi-dotnet

This sample works with MSAL alpha library and broken with preview version of the library. Can somebody point me to a same sample working with preview version of MSAL?

Thanks,
Sanjay A.

Comment: This MSAL library is still no published and may change. And the code sample doesn't support the preview version MSAL since the library make lots of change. For example, the class `TokenCache` is changed to `sealed`. If you want the example to support the MSAL preview version, you may open a new issue on the project page on GitHub. If you have any specific issues you can leave it on this forum.

Comment: Thank you @FeiXue
As per this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2017/06/22/web-api-and-custom-scope-with-azure-ad-v2-endpoint/
you can get access token for custom scopes. But it does not work when you pass openid or offline_access in the scope.
Does Azure AD v2 does not support Openid connect for custom web api? 
Any clue on this?

Comment: I am also able to reproduce this issue and trying to report this issue. I will be back if there is any update.